# coreeng.h:7: error: undefined reference to `vtable for coreEng'

Tags: c++, qt

I have tried running qmake to rebuild the Makefiles but creator still gives me the same error  coreeng.h:7: error: undefined reference to `vtable for coreEng': I am not accessing the class correctly.

//coreeng.h

```
#ifndef COREENG_H
#define COREENG_H
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

class coreEng : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
        public:
            explicit coreEng(QObject *parent = 0);
        private slots:

        public slots:
            void connect();
            void url();
            void finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply);


        private:
            QNetworkAccessManager* nam;

};

#endif // COREENG_H
```

//coreeng.cpp

```
#include "coreeng.h"
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QImageReader>

coreEng::coreEng(QObject* parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}


void coreEng::connect(){
    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void coreEng::url(){
    QUrl url("http://www.forum.nokia.wiki");
    QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}

void coreEng::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply){

    QVariant statusCodeV = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);

    QVariant redirectionTargetUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);

    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {

        QImageReader imageReader(reply);
        QImage pic = imageReader.read();

        QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
        QString string(bytes); // string
    }

    else
    {

    }

    delete reply;

}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <coreeng.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    coreEng mConnect;
    mConnect.connect();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Is that the full error?

Comment: @0x499602D2    http://i.imgur.com/1gTvvX1.png   C:\Qt5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\miniHTTP\coreeng.h:7: error: undefined reference to `vtable for coreEng'    pretty much.

Comment: remove all the intermediary files manually (including Makefile) and build again

Comment: @Murat Seker Same issue   http://i.imgur.com/qqXir4q.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a GUI error.
restarted creator and this particular situation went away.